# Android BroadcastReceiver : having more then one service

Tags: android, upload, download, broadcastreceiver, wifi

I'm tryinig to create an application to download and upload file, from my android phone.
Well from a broadcastReceiver for wifi ,i want to do two services ,one for the donwload and the second for the upload. Well already i did a service to download.
I want to know if it's possible to do two consecutive services in the same brodcast receiver.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, there are no restrictions. You can launch both if you like.

Comment: ok ,thanks for replying.i would like to know your opinion about the idea. Every time there is new data from the broadcastreceiver (wifi changing state ),i'll lanche a service for download and a service for upload ,then again new data from brodcast receiver...Thank you in advance @WindsurferOak

Comment: Sounds perfectly fine. There's an event (the broadcast), and then there's the response to the event (launching of the service).